# How to represent bit fields (and send them) in Java

Tags: java, networking, bit-manipulation

In my current project I need to send over the network a parsed structure that contains some n-bit fields. for instance:

- protocol version: 1 byte
- messageId: 1 byte
- creationTime: 6 bytes
- traceId: 3 bits
- reliability: 7 bits
- Etc...

Thus, I created a simple POJO class to represent this for parsing & unparsing, but I have some doubts on what type to use for those fields, since this decision can make parsing & unparsing easy or a bit of a nightmare. I must say that the Message to be sent over the network has a very specific size constraint: it cannot surpass the sum of all fields.

I first tought in using bytes for everything and then have a Message.getBytes() method that will convert the message and for those fields that are less than a byte, use bitwise operations to discard the unnecessary bits.

Am I going in the right direction or there is another much simpler way to do this? I just feel I'm re-inventing the wheel here, this feels kinda boilerplate code...

Thanks!

EDIT: If anybody else stumbles here, I'll post how I solved this (thanks to a mate at work that helped me with these), so just keep reading:

Luckily enough, my protocol socket size rounds up to a fixed number of bytes (49) and those fields that are less than byte size, sum up a byte at then end, resulting in that I can combine both fields in a single byte prior parsing/unparsing.

That said, imagine I have two fields, say field1 and field2, first in 7 bits and the other just a bit. To combine those, I just do this trick:

```
byte resultingByte = short2Byte((short) ((field1 % 128) * 2 + (field2 ? 1 : 0)));
```

Note that both field1 and field2 are short type. I found this the most convenient way to work at the bit level. Thus, I mod first field, making sure I'm only getting 7 bits, move the bits to the left divining by 2 since only one bit is needed to be moved. Lastly I add the field 2 short, which can be 1 or 0. Then I have a short with the required values in the 8 Less Signigicant Bits.

I created commodity methods to convert from short2Byte, Long, and some others:

```
private byte [] to2Bytes(int in) {
    ByteBuffer ret = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
    int val = in % 65536;

    short s1 = (short) (val / 256);
    short s0 = (short) (val % 256);

    ret.put(short2Byte(s1));
    ret.put(short2Byte(s0));

    return ret.array();
}

private byte [] to4Bytes(long in) {
    ByteBuffer ret = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    long div = 4294967296L;
    long val = in % div;
    int rem = 0;

    short s3 = (short) (val / 16777216L);
    rem = (int) (val % 16777216L);
    short s2 = (short) (rem / 65536);
    rem = rem % 65536;
    short s1 = (short) (rem / 256);
    short s0 = (short) (rem % 256);

    ret.put(short2Byte(s3));
    ret.put(short2Byte(s2));
    ret.put(short2Byte(s1));
    ret.put(short2Byte(s0));

    return ret.array();
}

private byte [] time2Bytes(Long time) {
    ByteBuffer ret = ByteBuffer.allocate(6);
    String hex = Long.toHexString(time).toUpperCase();
    while (hex.length() < 12) {
        hex = "0" + hex;
    }

    while (hex.length() > 12) {
        hex = hex.substring(1);
    }

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            String strByte = "" + hex.charAt(i*2) + hex.charAt(i*2 + 1);
            short b = Short.parseShort(strByte, 16);
            if (b > 127) {
                b -= 256;
            }
            ret.put((byte) b);
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // Exception captured for correctness
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return ret.array();
}

private long bytes2time(byte b5, byte b4, byte b3, byte b2, byte b1, byte b0) {
    long l5, l4, l3, l2, l1, l0;
    l5 = byte2short(b5) * 1099511627776L;
    l4 = byte2short(b4) * 4294967296L;
    l3 = byte2short(b3) * 16777216L;
    l2 = byte2short(b2) * 65536L;
    l1 = byte2short(b1) * 256L;
    l0 = byte2short(b0) * 1L;
    return  l5 + l4 + l3 + l2 + l1 + l0;
}

private long bytes2long(byte b3, byte b2, byte b1, byte b0) {
    long l3, l2, l1, l0;
    l3 = byte2short(b3) * 16777216L;
    l2 = byte2short(b2) * 65536L;
    l1 = byte2short(b1) * 256L;
    l0 = byte2short(b0) * 1L;
    return  l3 + l2 + l1 + l0;
}

private int bytes2int(byte b1, byte b0) {
    return (int)byte2short(b1) * 256 + (int)byte2short(b0);
}

private short byte2short(byte b) {
    if (b < 0) {
        return (short) (b+256);
    }
    return (short)b;
}

private byte short2Byte(short s) {
    if (s < 128) {
        return (byte) s;
    }
    else {
        return (byte) (s-256);
    }
}
```

At the end I'm sending a byte array with 49 bytes. Unparsing is very similar process, obviously. There must be a proper way to do this, but well, it works...Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This will be a problem: "_I must say that the Message to be sent over the network has a very specific size constraint: it cannot surpass the sum of all fields_" What network protocol are you talking about?

Comment: I'm encapsulating the message in an UDP package. I don't mind packaging the message itself in several UDP packages, but the maximun message payload size is fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can to use [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) and [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class to write and read messages, but it can still become a nightmare even worse then pure bit manipulation (and it will affect performance)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking in using a BitSet. My doubt comes for those fields that are, say 6 bits, which I store in a byte. I can mask the values I want, but I'm not sure about how to iterate on a bit basis and add each bit in the BitSet...

Comment: I think you can implement iterator pattern for that. Also you can implement method like 'addBits(long source, int count)' to take 'count' less significant bits and add them to your BitSet

Comment: Why would be the first param a long in your example? I wonder...Most of the elements in my message are numeric, thus, I can use byte, short and int to represent them, but for those < 1 byte, I'm using byte. With the ByteBuffer I can add on a byte basis, but not less than that, thus, I'm not sure how to include something smaller than a byte to the ByteBuffer...

Comment: Because sometimes you need to pass unsigned numbers. So if you're using this method to add unsigned integer it will be logical to use long. Also I try not to underestimate people) just in case they are crazy enough to use 49 bit fields;)

Comment: Using ByteBuffer helps, but I'm adding "unnecessary" bits to the byte array whitin the ByteBuffer, since I'm not sure how to work at a bit-level yet. By the way, I've found this very nice article (http://java.sys-con.com/node/847250) that exposes a class to encapsulate bit manipulation, not exactly what I need, but close